# Shell script to download files from SFTP

Tags: shell, cron, sftp

I am working on building a application that will pull data from SFTP.

Basically I have written a shell script that's run on a cron job daily.

Now I want to know if I can implement some logic in the shell script that will scan the files (for security threats – such as: software viruses, worms, Trojans, adware, etc.) before downloading. Is that possible and how?

Comment: For a scan to happen, the scanning software needs access to the binary file. In other words, the scanning software must be in the same place where the files to be scanned is. So, in order to scan the files "at the source" you'd have to be able to trigger some remote scanning software from your script - which I think might not be under your control.

The suggestion is to perform the download from your script to a temporary location on your local system, and then trigger a scan from the script. If the scan is clean, then you can move the downloaded file to the final destination else delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to "remote control" your SFTP session. There are several ways to do this, but I don't see, how you can scan a file for a virus *using the (S)FTP* protocol, without downloading it. This would require to execute a program on the remote side, and for what I know, FTP does not support this.

Maybe ssh would be the tool of choice. First open a ssh session, do all the checking of the files, then transfer them with FTP. If you are really paranoid, you can calculate the MD5 sum of the file before the checking, and after the download, and verify that they are identical.